# A problem of CellExpression copy to SE

Tags: discussion

`Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{
  "string", "=", 
   "\"\<<img src=\\\"/HTMLFiles\\\\Help\\\\Help\\\\Help_1.gif\\\" \
alt=\\\"Help_1.gif\\\" width=\\\"882\\\" height=\\\"382\\\" \
style=\\\"vertical-align:middle\\\" /><img src=\\\"/HTMLFiles\\\\Help\
\\\\Help\\\\spikeyIcon.png\\\" alt=\\\"Spikey\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \
height=\\\"21\\\" style=\\\"padding-right:2px; border:0px solid \
white; vertical-align:middle;\\\" />\>\""}], ";"}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{
  3.5876442026958013`*^9, {3.5876443775458155`*^9, 
   3.58764441727009*^9}}]`

---

Above is OK, but how can I make it into a (four spaces)markdown? Content in the CellExpression is Space sensitive.

I'm not sure about this question completely.

At present I found that new lines[by Enter to form four spaces markdown codes] will change the spaces in the HTML codes, and after copy the (four spaces) markdown codes back to Notebook to do some String Manipulation, there will be something wrong, for example, maybe there is a `\n` between `<img` and `src`

Answer (score 1):

You can put the expression in double accent ``  so the accents inside will not be indicating end of code section.

`` Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{
  "string", "=", 
   "\"\<<img src=\\\"/HTMLFiles\\\\Help\\\\Help\\\\Help_1.gif\\\" \
alt=\\\"Help_1.gif\\\" width=\\\"882\\\" height=\\\"382\\\" \
style=\\\"vertical-align:middle\\\" /><img src=\\\"/HTMLFiles\\\\Help\
\\\\Help\\\\spikeyIcon.png\\\" alt=\\\"Spikey\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \
height=\\\"21\\\" style=\\\"padding-right:2px; border:0px solid \
white; vertical-align:middle;\\\" />\>\""}], ";"}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{
  3.5876442026958013`*^9, {3.5876443775458155`*^9, 
   3.58764441727009*^9}}] ``

Comment: I know that's not the answer to your question but I think this way it looks better and is more safe.